# How to create a 8x12 heatplot from a single column of values?

Tags: r, matrix, heatmap

I have a column of values in R that represents measurements from a 8x12 grid:

Here are the first four rows of measurements. A1-H1 represents row 1 in the grid, A2-H2 represents row 2 etc. I have 12 rows in total. How do I convert this data into a matrix of 8x12 (8X4 in this dummy example) so that I can create a heatmap that visualises the relative Weight values in a way that recapitulates the original shape of the grid that has been lost when the data is imported as a single column?

Thank you in advance.

```
Cell    Weight
A1  2
B1  2
C1  2
D1  2
E1  2
F1  2
G1  2
H1  2
A2  2
B2  0.1
C2  2
D2  4
E2  2
F2  0.1
G2  2
H2  2
A3  2
B3  2
C3  2
D3  2
E3  2
F3  4
G3  2
H3  2
A4  2
B4  2
C4  6
D4  2
E4  2
F4  2
G4  2
H4  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need matrix for that, just extract row/column information from you table and use it for `geom_tile`:

```
df$Row <- gsub("[A-Z]", "", df$Cell)
df$Col <- gsub("[0-9]", "", df$Cell)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(Col, Row, fill = Weight)) +
    geom_tile()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use libraries `tidyr` and `dplyr`:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE, text='Cell    Weight
A1  2
B1  2
C1  2
D1  2
E1  2
F1  2
G1  2
H1  2
A2  2
B2  0.1
C2  2
D2  4
E2  2
F2  0.1
G2  2
H2  2
A3  2
B3  2
C3  2
D3  2
E3  2
F3  4
G3  2
H3  2
A4  2
B4  2
C4  6
D4  2
E4  2
F4  2
G4  2
H4  2')
m <- df %>% separate(Cell, into=c('column','rows'), sep=1) %>% spread(column, Weight) 
rownames(m) <- m$rows
m$rows <- NULL
heatmap(as.matrix(m))
```